# Combine multiple json merging duplicates and adding values for a specific key in python

Tags: python, json, merge

I've looked around for a method to do this, but I can only find bits and pieces and keep getting stuck.
I want to add two sets of json, retaining all properties but adding the `total` value if a duplicate `owner` value exists.

```
json1 = [{"total":101,"owner":"User1","type":8,"team":"Team1"},
{"total":44,"owner":"User2","type":8,"team":"Team1"},
{"total":22,"owner":"User3","type":8,"team":"Team2"}]

json2 = [{"total":12,"owner":"User1","type":8,"team":"Team1"},
{"total":33,"owner":"User3","type":8,"team":"Team2"},
{"total":18,"owner":"User4","type":8,"team":"Team1"}]
```

I want to have the output look like this

```
finaljson = [{"total":113,"owner":"User1","type":8,"team":"Team1"},
{"total":44,"owner":"User2","type":8,"team":"Team1"},
{"total":55,"owner":"User3","type":8,"team":"Team2"},
{"total":18,"owner":"User4","type":8,"team":"Team1"}]
```

Alternatively, how would I reach my final `finaljson` if I had a single json set and wanted to find duplicate `owner` and merge `total` the same as above.

`mergedjson = json1.extend(json2)` becomes `finaljson`

Thanks!

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonmerge

Comment: I tried jsonmerge, it seems to overwrite my first array with the second when I merge.  I could be using it wrong.

Comment: This is just basic dictionary manipulation. If you keep getting stuck, try doing a really simple example, like merging `{"A":1}` with `{"A":2}` and see if you get expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, although this wont be the best solution.

```
def merge_json(json1, json2):
    data = {}
    for val in json1+json2:
        key = val["owner"]
        if key in data:
            data[key]['total'] = data[key]['total']+val['total']
        else:
            data[key] = val
    return list(data.values())
```

**[DEMO](https://repl.it/DoKf)**